# Setting up mail server for providing bulk email service

Tags: 14.04, email

As mailchimp & other online bulk email service provider companies allow their users to send bulk emails & keeps track of emails are sent / bounced / undelivered / opened / spammed / deleted

which utilities or packages do we need to install on ubuntu in order to provide such service ?
Is it POSTFIX MAILX..? Or Do we need to install & configure a mail server; If so which packages / binaries we use?

Answer (score 0):

You could do some of that through Postfix (and [a SASL authentication library](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl)). You could certainly allow users to send emails.

The "undelivered/opened" tracking is done by making every image in the email have unique URL for that recipient. When they are requested by the email client, you know your email to that person was delivered. This means you need to pre-process the emails to alter the URLs and then have something that's logging the requests on a webserver.

Similarly, usage tracking is done by converting any links in the email in a similar way... So that if they click them, they're actually sent via one of your scripts that logs your click and then sends you to the right place.

And what makes MailChimp (et al) most useful is fancy APIs so that users don't have to do all this stuff at their end. They can have HTML templates, submit email bodies and email lists (and MailChimp manages lists too). These are significant features that can be replicated but take significant developer time.

What I'm saying is **services like MailChimp aren't just SMTP relays**. They do a lot of other stuff around the email sending process that makes bulk-emailing easy. If you just want to be a relay, you can do that all with Postfix.